# Pattern matching how you can use the "when" keyword

Tags: c#

This is my sampler:

```
object[] input = new object[] {1, "", 2.3, 5, 8 };
int sum = 0;
foreach (var item in input)
{
    if (item is int count)
    sum += count;
}
Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7
It says here that you can use the "when" keyword to specify additional rules to the pattern.

I am trying add `when item > 5` but doesn't recognize the "when" keyword anywhere.

Where should it be added?

Comment: There is a specific example of using when in the article you linked. Have you tried that? Could you share the code you had for that and what error you got?

Comment: Are you sure, the required C# version is supported at your IDE?

Comment: The example in the page is for the `case` statement, not for the `if` statement

Comment: The when keyword (in this instance) is part of a switch expression allowing you to apply a more specific filter to `case`s

Comment: [Here](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2020/02/27/c-8-pattern-matching/) they do `if (input is int count && count > 100)`, so no when

Comment: To be fair, those docs start off a bit unclearly: _"Pattern matching supports `is` expressions and `switch` expressions. Each enables inspecting an object and its properties to determine if that object satisfies the sought pattern. You use the `when` keyword to specify additional rules to the pattern."_ - implying you can use the `when` wherever you can use `is`.

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek I was based on the text that colleague inserted below. I realized that I could use the "when" keyword with "is" as well, not just "switch".

Comment: @xanatos ok, thanks, it wasn't clearly written.

Comment: @xanatos but for my sampler '&& item > 5' throw "item is object" and I have to cast item to int. Still, this solution seems okay.

Comment: @SilnyToJa You must reuse the new variable you introduced `if (item is int count && count > 5)`

Comment: @xanatos oh indeed, my mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Use the `when` keyword in a `switch` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/when#when-in-a-switch-statement):

```cs
object[] input = new object[] {1, "", 2.3, 5, 8 };
int sum = 0;
foreach (var item in input)
{
    switch (item)
    {
        case int count when count > 5:
            sum += count;
            break;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

Note that in the [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#pattern-matching) section you used for reference, they mention both `is` and `switch` expressions:

> Pattern matching supports `is` expressions and `switch` expressions. Each enables inspecting an object and its properties to determine if that object satisfies the sought pattern. You use the `when` keyword to specify additional rules to the pattern.

Though according to the reference link above for the `when` keyword, the filter appears to only be supported within a `switch` statement. As [xanatos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/613130/xanatos) points out, this is likely because you can filter the `is` expression using the `&&` operator like `if (item is int count && count > 5)`

Comment: Add that with `if` you can do a `&&`: `if (item is int item2 && item2 > 5)`. With `case` there isn't the `&&` so they needed the `when` keyword

Answer (score 0):

```
object[] input = new object[] {1, "", 2.3, 5, 8 };
int sum = 0;
foreach (var item in input)
{
    
    switch(item){
      case int n when n>5:
      sum +=n;
      break;
      default:
      break;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

Try this.